# How to render just a BitmapFilter to BMD?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, filter, bitmap

How would you render a BitmapFilter (such as DropShadowFilter) applied to a sprite, to a seperate BitmapData Layer? which would then be placed beneath all objects.

For instance if you have two rectangular sprites overlapping each other, with a DropShadowFilter applied to each, the result would be the filter overlaying and obscuring the other rectangular sprite - as shown below.

**note:** each filter may have different settings and so I cant just apply a uniform filter to a containing sprite. **also:** ideally this solution will be scalable to handle many animated sprites at the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the easiest way to do this is to keep an outline copy of each of your Sprites, to which you apply the DropShadowFilter. On the filter, set `dropShadowFilter.hideObject = true;` - this will render only the shadow. Then add all the outline shadows to a single container Sprite and use `addChildAt(container,0)`, so it will be rendered below everything else.

Comment: thanks that does sound like a good way to do this, will experiment.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be drawing each `DisplayObject` with it's filter's property `knockout` set to `true` to a `BitmapData` object, then reseting each filter's `knockout` to original state. A quick example to demonstrate this:

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
s.graphics.drawRect(0,0,40,40);
s.graphics.endFill();
var shadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter();
s.filters = [shadow];


function renderFilter(sprite:Sprite):Bitmap
{
   var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sprite.width * 1.2, sprite.height * 1.2, true); //extra 20% for the filter data, you might have to adjust this value depending on your filter's size
  var filter:DropShadowFilter = sprite.filters[0];
  var originalKnockout:Boolean = filter.knockout;
  filter.knockout = true;
  bd.draw(sprite);
  filter.knockout = originalKnockout;
  sprite.filters[0] = filter;
  var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
  return bitmap;
}
renderFilter(s); // here you have filter's rendering;
```

Comment: cheers for a great answer, I need to experiment a little but it currently runs too slowly

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for BitmapData.applyFilter(). It applies any BitmapFilter type to your BitmapData object. Bitmap filter is the parent class for a bunch of Filter types, including Blur, Glow, and Shader filters.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#applyFilter()

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/BitmapFilter.html

Comment: cheers but I don't think that's what I am looking for, rather a way to just render the filter that's applied to a sprite.